# Rank of non-zero integral ideal as a module

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am reading Pierre Samuel Algebraic Theory of Numbers. 
On pages 57,

> Let $K$ be a number field and let $n$ be its degree.
>   $\sigma$ is the *canonical imbedding* of $K$ in $\mathbf R^{r_1} \times \mathbf C^{r_2}$  , where $n = r_1 + 2r_2$
>
> Proposition 2. Let $d$ be the absolute discriminant of $K$, let $A$ be the ring of intgers in $K$, and let $\mathfrak a$ be a non-zero integral ideal of $A$. Then $\sigma (A)$ and $\sigma (\mathfrak a )$ are lattices. Morevore,
>   $ v(\sigma (A)) = 2^{-r_2} |d| ^{1/2}$ and $ v(\sigma)\mathfrak a)) = 2 ^{-r_2}|d|^{1/2}N(\mathfrak a).$
>
> *Proof.* We Know that $A$ and $\mathfrak a$ are free $\mathbf Z$ -modules of rank $n$, so we may apply Proposition 1. $\cdots$

I understand why $A$ be a free $\mathbf Z$-modules of rank $n$, but why $\mathfrak a$ is so? Can not the rank of $\mathfrak a$ be strictly smaller than $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because $\mathfrak a$ is a sub $\mathbf Z$-module of the free module $A$, hence it is free, and it has the same rank since tensoring with $\mathbf Q$ gives the field of fractions of $A$ in both cases.

Comment: I think I have some misconcept for integral ideal. Integral ideal of $Q$ is a fractional ideal of $Q$ which lies entirely in $R$(here $Q$ is the field of ractions of $R$). In the Proposition, $\mathfrak a $ is an integral ideal of $A$. Then $A$ is the fileld of fractions of what?

Comment: An integral ideal of $A$ is an ordinary ideal. $A$ is not a field of fractions, but it *has* a field of fractions, say $K$, and it is known that $K\simeq A\otimes_{\mathbf Z}\mathbf Q$, so that $\mathfrak a\otimes_{\mathbf Z}\mathbf Q\simeq K$. The rank of $\mathfrak a$ is equal to the rank of $A$, since it is the dimension of the tensor product over $\mathbf Q$.